# SUMIF based on array

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

Not sure if I'm overlooking something but I can't seem to find an answer for this. I have two sheets:

Sheet 1

```
country   |   cost
---------------------
DE        |    5
FR        |    4
US        |    3
MX        |    2
AT        |    1
```

Sheet 2

```
region    | country
---------------------
EU        |   DE
EU        |   FR
AM        |   US
AM        |   MX
EU        |   AT
```

What I want is the sum of cost of all European Countries. In the past I simply used a column C with VLOOKUP for the region in Sheet 1 and then SUMIF'd this data. I'd like to avoid this, because the volume of data in Sheet 1 is huge and dynamic.

I could of course use

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!country, Sheet2!region="EU")
```

which would return an array of {"DE", "AT", "FR"}, but I cannot use

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!cost, Sheet1!country=FILTER(Sheet2!country, Sheet2!region="EU"))
```

Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(sumif(A:A,filter(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A="EU"),B:B)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, replace the VLOOKUP with an INDEX MATCH,

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:A$6, MATCH(A3, Sheet2!$B$2:B$6, 0)))

where col B in sheet 2 are the countries, and col A the region

Comment: The question is: How can I get the SUM of the regions. Not the countries regions themselves.

Comment: You could have used the sumif I provided in my previous post ? Or alternatively use a query..

Comment: Sumif expects a criterion. My question was how I can use an array as that criterion or what a sensible alternative would be. This solves nothing of that sort, as the data returned is not an array.

Comment: I see no other way than using index match to bring the regions over and then use a query e.g. =query(A1:D6, "Select D, sum(B) group by D", 1) to sum the cost and have the regions listed. That way you won't need SUMIF. Maybe someone else has a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use VLOOKUP you would have to change the lay-out of sheet 2 so that it has country in col 1 and region in col 2

Then you can use VLOOKUP in col C of first sheet

=VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet4!$A$2:$B$6, 2)
Drag down as far as needed

And for the sumif:

=sumif(C3:C7, "EU", B3:B7)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as I said that should be avoided as the sheets are quite big

Comment: You could have used to SUMIF I provided earlier, or alternatively a QUERY. Here's a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0KgZxSeMHf3vbIFDiixZMT4QEIl8MVibvZp-X1a8Sg/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: As much as I appreciate the effort - what you're doing is a more complicated version of VLOOKUP and then a SUMIF based on that. I know how to do that - but it doesn't answer my question at all.